# 3 Graphs horizontally and equations for each one

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, equations, horizontal-alignment, minipage

I used the answers from similar discussion to create a somehow working graph, the problem is that nothing really aligns well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.6]
        \begin{axis}[
            domain=-2:2,
            ]
            \addplot+[mark=none,red] {tanh(\x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{tanh(x) function}
  \begin{equation}
    tanh(x) = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}
    \label{eq:tanh}
  \end{equation}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.6]
        \begin{axis}[
            domain=-4:4,
            ]
            \addplot[blue,mark=none]   {1/ (1+e^(-x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{sigmoid function}
  \begin{equation}
    \sigma  (x) =  \frac{\mathrm{1} }{\mathrm{1} + e^{-x} }
    \label{eq:sigmoid}
  \end{equation}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.6]
        \begin{axis}[
            domain=-4:4,
            ]
            \addplot+[mark=none,red,domain=-3:0] {0};
            \addplot+[mark=none,red,domain=0:5] {x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{ReLU function}
  \begin{equation}
     ReLU(x) =\begin{cases} x       & \quad \text{if } x \geq\text{ 0}\\ 0 & \quad \text{if } x \text{ < 0}\end{cases}
     \label{eq:relu}
  \end{equation}
\endminipage
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You could top align the minipages to avoid the problem. Can you make a compilable test document?

Comment: Sure gimme a second to edit it so it should compile, just for completeness sake im gonna include all the packages i used in my document.

Comment: Thanks for the top align hint, the graphs now align pretty well, the text and the label numbers are still like above though.

Any suggestions on how i could make them look more uniform ?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution, if anyone ever stumbles upon the same problem:

1. Use `[t]` to top align the minipages.

   ```
   \minipage[t]{0.32\textwidth}
   ```
2. Resize the boxes for the equations until they fit

   ```
   \begin{equation}
     \resizebox{0.6\hsize}{!}{
       $tanh(x) = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}$
       }
       \label{eq:tanh}
     \end{equation}
   ```

Maybe not the best solution but it works and looks correct.

[image]